# Use of "would" in this sentence?

Tags: will-would

I wanted to know why we use **would** in this sentence.

> If you feel you don't have the vocabulary required, you could try to gently shift the conversation to an area where you know a greater number of relevant words. Of course, this shift must be to a related area rather than a totally new topic, unless there is a complete silence where it **would** be justified to change topic.

Comment: It's not the only option but it's valid. Why don't you think *would* is correct? What would you prefer? [*Unless=if not*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv272.shtml) so it follows similar rules to *if* to express conditionals. Are you familiar with the use of *would* in conditionals?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the entry for would in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would), one of the meanings related to  possibility is described as:

> used with if in conditional sentences (= sentences that refer to what happens if something else happens